# Filtering SQL query

Tags: sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  Room.RoomID, 
  Room.RoomNumber, 
  Room.PhoneExtension, 
  Room.SpecialNotes ,
  RoomType.Description

FROM        
  Room 

INNER JOIN
  RoomType 
ON 
  Room.TypeID = RoomType.TypeID

LEFT JOIN
  Reservation
ON
  Room.RoomID = Reservation.RoomID

WHERE
  Room.DeleteFlag=0 AND
  (Reservation.ResStatus <> 'Occupied' OR Reservation.ResStatus = NULL) AND 
  (Reservation.ResStatus <> 'Reserved' OR Reservation.ResStatus = NULL) AND 
  (Reservation.ResStatus <> 'Confirmed' OR Reservation.ResStatus = NULL)

ORDER BY
  RoomNumber
```

Hello, I have a delete room form that is supposed to flag a room as deleted in the database. The room id is posted to reservations table as well when a reservation is made. I'm trying to get all the rooms that do not appear in the reservations, or if they are in that table then they should not be reserved, occupied or confirmed.

The query is giving me back all the rooms that appear exclusively on the reservations, regardless of the reservation status, and no rooms that do not have a reservation status.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe i missunderstand your question but try this :

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
    Room.RoomID, 
    Room.RoomNumber, 
    Room.PhoneExtension, 
    Room.SpecialNotes ,
    RoomType.Description
FROM            Room 
    INNER JOIN  RoomType    ON Room.TypeID = RoomType.TypeID
    /*LEFT  JOIN  Reservation ON Room.RoomID = Reservation.RoomID*/
WHERE   Room.DeleteFlag=0 And Room.RoomID not in (select RoomID from Reservation where
    (Reservation.ResStatus <> 'Occupied' OR Reservation.ResStatus = NULL)
    AND (Reservation.ResStatus <> 'Reserved' OR Reservation.ResStatus = NULL)
    AND (Reservation.ResStatus <> 'Confirmed' OR Reservation.ResStatus = NULL))
ORDER BY    RoomNumber
```

Comment: since you are reversing the query in the second select, I changed the <> to =, did not include the null values and joined them with or instead of AND. works a treat, thanks for the hints